# Assigning Dynamic Table Name and LinkedServer Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to dynamically change the Table name specified as well as the LinkedServer name specified without causing the Remote Oracle SQL string (>8000 chars) to be referenced as a scalar variable, which causes my script to break ?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1 EXEC ( @mySQL ) AT Linked_Server_1
```

Comment: When i hardcode both the table name & linkedserver name respectively it works fine. My problem is I need it to accept dynamic values for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the whole statement dynamic like:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max)
SET @s = 'INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1 EXEC ( ''' + @mySQL + ''' ) AT Linked_Server_1'
EXEC( @s )
```

You may need to escape any apostrophes in your @mySQL variable.  It gets kind of crazy:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max)
SET @s = 'INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1 EXEC ( ''' + replace(@mySQL, '''', '''''') + ''' ) AT Linked_Server_1'
EXEC( @s )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, coupled with the apostrophes escaping worked like a charm :)